# How to fix no matching function for call error and ' ' was not declared in this scope errors

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to create a new UDP application with which I can control the process of generating packets and the process of sending packets i.e. I have separate parameters for packet generation and send interval.

When I am running the code, getting the following errors:

> inet/applications/udpapp/UdpOwnApp.cc:134:29: error: no matching
> function for call to ‘omnetpp::cQueue::insert(const
> inet::IntrusivePtrinet::ApplicationPacket&)’
> queue.insert(payload);
> ^ inet/applications/udpapp/UdpOwnApp.cc:157:15: error: ‘payload’ was not
> declared in this scope
> queue.pop(payload);
> ^~~~~~~

The chunk of code is given below:

```
void UdpOwnApp::generatePacket()
{
        const auto& payload = makeShared<ApplicationPacket>();
        payload->setChunkLength(B(par("messageLength")));
        payload->setSequenceNumber(numGenerate);
        payload->addTag<CreationTimeTag>()->setCreationTime(simTime());
        queue.insert(payload);
        simtime_t d = simTime() + par("generateInterval");
        if (stopTime < SIMTIME_ZERO || d < stopTime) {
            selfMsg->setKind(GENERATE);
            scheduleAt(d, selfMsg);
        }
        else {
            selfMsg->setKind(STOP);
            scheduleAt(stopTime, selfMsg);
        }
}
void UdpOwnApp::sendPacket()
{
    std::ostringstream str;
    str << packetName << "-" << numSent;
    Packet *packet = new Packet(str.str().c_str());
    if(dontFragment)
        packet->addTag<FragmentationReq>()->setDontFragment(true);
    queue.pop(payload);
    packet->insertAtBack(payload); 
    L3Address destAddr = chooseDestAddr();
    emit(packetSentSignal, packet);
    socket.sendTo(packet, destAddr, destPort);
    numSent++;
}
```

Would anyone suggest if the code is correct and how to resolve the errors?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration of `insert()` is following:

```
virtual void insert(cObject *obj);
```

Therefore one cannot pass other object that `cObject` or derived class. You may use an instance of `Packet` because it inherits from `cObject`. So the code may look like:

```
void UdpOwnApp::generatePacket() {
    const auto& payload = makeShared<ApplicationPacket>();
    payload->setChunkLength(B(par("messageLength")));
    payload->setSequenceNumber(numGenerate);
    payload->addTag<CreationTimeTag>()->setCreationTime(simTime());

    std::ostringstream str;
    str << packetName << "-" << numSent;
    Packet *packet = new Packet(str.str().c_str());
    packet->insertAtBack(payload);
    queue.insert(packet);
    simtime_t d = simTime() + par("generateInterval");
    if (stopTime < SIMTIME_ZERO || d < stopTime) {
       selfMsg->setKind(GENERATE);
       scheduleAt(d, selfMsg);
    } else {
       selfMsg->setKind(STOP);
       scheduleAt(stopTime, selfMsg);
    }
}

void UdpOwnApp::sendPacket() {
    if (queue.isEmpty()) {
        // no packets in queue
    } else {
        cObject * obj = queue.pop();
        Packet * packet = dynamic_cast<Packet*>(obj);
        if (packet) {
            if (dontFragment)
                packet->addTag<FragmentationReq>()->setDontFragment(true);
            L3Address destAddr = chooseDestAddr();
            emit(packetSentSignal, packet);
            socket.sendTo(packet, destAddr, destPort);
            numSent++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jerzy, this removes the errors but when i run omnetpp.ini, no packets are generated, and so no packets are sent at all. Number of generated packets and sent packets are just 0. Would you suggest why?

Comment: Jerzy, I tested that with existing ned and omnetpp.ini files for sensornetwork. Just added the parameter for packet generation in "ini" file. Will it work if i mention the file name only because i cannot create post with so long codes and these codes are already in INET?

Comment: If you could suggest me here, it would be better. Thank you

Comment: You should definitely add a new question with your problem. Reasons: 1) You didn't write why you think that number of generated packets is equal to 0 - provided code doesn't contain any statistic for recording this value. 2) You didn't write when and where do you call `generatePacket()` and `sendPacket()`. 3) You didn't write what parameters you added and what values you set in `omnetpp.ini`. 4) `INET` doesn't contain kind `GENERATE` - you didn't explain the meaning of `GENERATE` as well as how msg with this kind is handled. Without these information no-one is able to help you.